# Django display survey questioner with different choices in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on a survey app where users that have administrator role can login to the admin dasboard and create surveys. A survey can have multiple questioniors. When creating a survey the admin users can add either checkbox choice, radio choice or a text box option to a question.
At the moment these functionality is working fine, what i need help with is how to display the survey questions to the surveyor page. How can i display all the questioners with option such as checkbox, textbox etc.

The current template can only display the questions with radio choices.

```html
class Survey(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    archive = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Question(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enter_question = models.CharField(max_length=900)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.enter_question


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    choice_check = models.CharField(max_length=100, null= True)
```

```html
<div class = "jumbotron container centerdv header-top">
        <h2>{{survey.title}}</h2>
    </div>

<div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <form method = "post" action =#>

    <input type = "hidden" name = "survey_id" value = {{survey.id}}>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for question in questions %}


                <div class="p-2">
                    <h4 class="header">
                    Question {{ forloop.counter }}: {{ question.enter_question }}
                </h4>
                </div>

        {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
             <div class="p-2">
            <input type="radio" name ="question{{question.id}}" value={{choice.id}}>
                {{choice.choice}}
             </div>
        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}


        <div class="p-2">
            <input type = "submit" value = "Complete!" class = "btn btn-lg btn-success">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting APP!

if i am making the app. I may define the `Question` model abstract, and derive `TextQuestion`, `SelectQuestion`, etc. for each type of questions. All of them have `survey` and `enter_question` from base class, and all of them have an `input` field which is `CharField`, `TextField`, etc.

For example, the `CheckQuestion` should have the input as `BooleanField`. Then the `modelform` will use `ckeckbox` as widget by default.

For a `SelectQuestion`, the choices can be saved in an extra field. For example, `choices = models.JsonField(default=list)`. Then define the form to get the choices dynamically from `choices` field. Like:

```
class SelectQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
...
  input = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[])
...
  def __init__(self,):
    super().__init__()
    self.fields[input].choices = self.instance.get_choices() # implement in model class.
```

Comment: when you said all of them will have an input field eg: CharField, TextField, etc.. are you saying that I shouldn't have the choice model?

Comment: @user11766958 The `choice model` is just like a different name of my `SelectQuestion`. it provides options and let user to pick one..

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that out but it didn't work out the way I wanted it because you can only add one choice to a multiple-choice question. so I have to recreate my model. This is what I did and it works the way I wanted.

```html
class Survey(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    archive = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Question(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enter_question = models.CharField(max_length=900)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.enter_question


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class TextChoice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class CheckChoice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_check = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class SurveyAnswer(models.Model):
    orig_survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class QuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # text_answer = models.ForeignKey(TextChoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check_answer = models.ForeignKey(CheckChoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    survey_answer = models.ForeignKey(SurveyAnswer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```